# Server error in '/' Application in Mvc Music Store ASP.Net MVC Sample Ported to Mono

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mono, monodevelop

I'm currently porting the [Mvc Music Store example](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/) to Mono, and it going very well, but I've run into a snag with a trailing slash on one of the routes. On the master page is the following link

```
<a href="/Store/">Store</a>
```

When I run the application and navigate to /Store/ I get the following error

```
Server Error in '/' Application

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Store/

Version information: Mono Runtime Version: 2.6.7 (tarball Wed Jul 14 17:55:26 UTC 2010); ASP.NET Version: 2.0.50727.1433
```

However when I take away the trailing slash it works fine. I've seen other posts and questions that would indicate this is a problem with Windows virtual directories when deployed to IIS, but I'm not sure what the problem is on linux using openSUSE 11.3 with Mono 2.6.7 and MonoDevelop 2.4.

Comment: What is your server configuration?  XSP, FastCGI, mod_mono?  If you're using FastCGI or mod_mono, you could use a rewrite module to handle trailing slashes...

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that. I'm running through MonoDevelop so this is under XSP.

Comment: I've got a similar problem but it's for the root domain. i.e. http://domain.com doesn't work but http://domain.com/home does work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the details of this but I suggest you try it with the Mono 2.8 previews, and if it still fails, file a bug.